# Is Ubuntu planning to have something similar to Akonadi?

Tags: metadata, pim

Does Ubuntu have plans to integrate [Akonadi](http://community.kde.org/KDE_PIM/Akonadi) or a similar functionality in future ([Wikipedia - Akonadi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akonadi))?

Comment: Why do you use a link shortener here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under Gnome (and Unity) [Evolution Data Server](http://www.go-evolution.org/EDS_Architecture), a part of the Evolution PIM suite, provides similar functionality for task, calendar, and addressbook information.  It is also used in Nokia's Maemo platform to store contact data.

I am not aware of anything offering similar functionality for e-mail data, but [Desktop Couch](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Specifications/desktopcouch) could be used in that manner.  The present lack of a standard data schema for representing e-mail as CouchDB documents would make interoperability between different applications using it as a data store difficult, however.